# HTML/CSS horizontal navbar centered with picture in the middle

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a problem with my navbar, i want to create a horizontal navbar with links and a picture in the middle. The picture is already fine, but the links arent in line. I want the links in the middle of the toolbar.
very much thank you in advance for your help.

P.S.:
I have to write some more text because the code is to long and i have no idea what more informations you shouldn't need, but if you have some questions feel free to ask them.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}

.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}

/* HEADER */
.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #364d63;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-form
.center {
  padding: 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="gruppen.html" class="col-2 center">Gruppen</a></li>
      <li><a href="shows.html" class="col-2 center">Shows</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="col-4 center"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32877/logo-thing.png" width="200" alt="Logo"></a></a></li>
      <li><a href="geschichte.html" class="col-2 center">Geschichte</a></li>
    <li><a href="bilder.html" class="col-2 center">Bilder</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    .nav {
  background-color: #364d63;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  flex-grow:1;
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Update your css by this and you will be good to go.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer, you helped me a lot :D

Comment: @HimangshuMondal what is the reason behind using `display: inline-block` with `display: flex`? and what is the purpose of `min-height`? what if the logo size change?

Comment: @patelarpan yes that's a mistake of using display:inline-block with display:flex, thanks for correcting. I might have miss that. Your answer is the best for this question.

Comment: then upvote my answer :) @HimangshuMondal and correct your answer so it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display:flex`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* HEADER */
.nav {
  background-color: #364d63;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;

   list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  flex-grow:1;
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}


.nav  {
 
}
```

```html
<header>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="gruppen.html">Gruppen</a></li>
      <li><a href="shows.html">Shows</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32877/logo-thing.png" width="200" alt="Logo"></a></li>
      <li><a href="geschichte.html">Geschichte</a></li>
    <li><a href="bilder.html" >Bilder</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout), one suggestion is to move `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` from `<a>` elements to `<li>` elements.

I also removed spaces from between `<li>` elements to avoid unwanted whitespace.

It's unclear how you'd like to handle list items that are too narrow for their contents.
I've simply set `overflow:hidden`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  /*float: left;*/
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}
.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}


.nav {
  background-color: #364d63;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav .center {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="col-2 center"><a href="gruppen.html">Gruppen</a>
    </li><li class="col-2 center"><a href="shows.html">Shows</a>
    </li><li class="col-4 center"><a href="index.html"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32877/logo-thing.png" width="200" alt="Logo"></a>
    </li><li class="col-2 center"><a href="geschichte.html">Geschichte</a>
    </li><li class="col-2 center"><a href="bilder.html">Bilder</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```